# What do rings do in the Blue Sphere bonus game?

Tags: sonic-mania

Every Blue Sphere stage in Sonic Mania has a preset amount of rings to collect.

I haven't been able to notice any gameplay changes when collecting them. They don't seem to change Sonic's speed, nor do I keep the rings after completing the bonus stage.

What does collecting rings do in Sonic Mania's Blue Sphere game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[According to Eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-08-18-sonic-mania-special-stages-chaos-emeralds-gold-medals-ufo-blue-sphere-4843), collecting every ring in a bonus stage earns you a 'Perfect', which is required for getting a Gold Metal.**

> The trick to getting a Perfect is to collect every ring on a stage.
>   You may notice you can finish a stage without collecting all the
>   rings, despite seemingly collecting all you can see; that's because
>   you can convert spheres into rings by creating an outline around
>   groups of blue spheres. These can be squares or rectangles, groups
>   that already have partial outlines already completed, or have unusual
>   shapes, such as bouncing spheres cutting into the corners.
>
> The trick, then, is to make sure you have converted all
>   groups of blue spheres into rings before you collect any remaining
>   individual blue spheres. The easiest way to do this is to leave behind
>   one or two blue spheres that cannot be converted, getting the
>   'Perfect', then going back to those spheres you left.
>
> **It's worth noting that, as mentioned in our Sonic Mania unlockables
>   page, getting all gold medals doesn't unlock anything in game - only
>   Silvers is required. It's only if you want all Trophies or
>   Achievements that Gold is worth aiming for.**

[image: Perfect screen]
<sub>Screenshot from [Giantbomb's 'Quick Look: Sonic Mania'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSJLhgxkfQQ&feature=youtu.be&t=350)</sub>

#### Sources

- Eurogamer: [Sonic Mania special stages - How to get Chaos Emeralds and Gold Medals from UFO, Blue Sphere stages](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-08-18-sonic-mania-special-stages-chaos-emeralds-gold-medals-ufo-blue-sphere-4843)
- Giant Bomb: [Quick Look - Sonic Mania](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSJLhgxkfQQ)